# error: missing return statement coin flipping code

Tags: java

So I am supposed to right a code that flips an unfair coin a 100 times.  You receive 1 dollar if you get heads(the slightly better chanced side) and loss a dollar for tails.  At the end of each turn it is supposed to return the value of integer winnings until the end of the 100 flips.  I am getting the error below:

```
CoinFlipExperiment.java:18: error: missing return statement
     }
     ^ 1 error
```

Anybody have some ideas?

```
public class CoinFlipExperiment {

 static public int coinFlipExperiment (){
      int winnings = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i<= 100; i++)  {
           double flip = Math.random();
                if (flip< 0.505) {            //heads
                   winnings = winnings + 1;

                }
                else  {                       //tails
                   winnings = winnings - 1;   

                }
                   System.out.println( winnings );
       }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args)  {
      int amount = coinFlipExperiment ();
           System.out.println ("Win/loss amount: " + amount);
   }
}
```

Comment: you haven't  included the return statement in coinFlipExperiment function

Comment: add this code in coinFlipExperiment function 
return winnings; after for loop

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return statement in your coinFlipExperiment method,It must be :

```
return winnings ;
```

as i guess.So try this:

```
static public int coinFlipExperiment (){
      int winnings = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i<= 100; i++)  {
           double flip = Math.random();
                if (flip< 0.505) {            //heads
                   winnings = winnings + 1;

                }
                else  {                       //tails
                   winnings = winnings - 1;   

                }
                   System.out.println( winnings );

       }
      return winnings ; 
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)  {
      int amount = coinFlipExperiment ();
           System.out.println ("Win/loss amount: " + amount);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your function `coinFlipExperiment` return an integer but you are not returning anything.

you need to return `winnings` at the end of `coinFlipExperiment`.